# why is insert into not working

Tags: php, mysql

I made this code

```
<?php
  mysql_connect ("localhost","root","root");
  mysql_select_db ("new");
  $newusername=$_POST ['newusername'];
  $newpassword=$_POST ['newpassword'];
  $submit=$_POST ['submit'];
  if($submit) {
    $newaccount= "INSERT INTO users (name,password) VALUES ("$newusername","$newpassword")";
    $result=mysql_query($newaccount);
    if ($result) {
      print "account has been created"."<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;login.php">";
    }
    else {
      echo " The account is already exist";
    }
  }
?>
```

but it says error on line 8 which is  " insert into" line

Comment: It's probably the way you've done your variables in the string, try using `'` instead of `"`. Also, please look into MySQLi or PDO as mysql is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with double quotes. You can add concatenation:

```
$newaccount = "INSERT INTO users (name,password) VALUES ('" . $newusername . "','" . $newpassword . "')";
```

P.S. Don't use mysql_* functions (mysql extension is deprecated), use mysqli_* instead.

Comment: The query will fail for string values `$newusername` and `$newpassword`

Comment: P.S. Don't recommend insecure SQL practices.

Answer (score 0):

You used wrong quoting:

```
$newaccount= "INSERT INTO users (name,password) VALUES ('$newusername','$newpassword')";
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I know about SQL injections but I didn`t want to make my answer more complicated than necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Sorting out the quotes and using mysql_real_escape_string to sanitise the input (and prevent an easy SQL injection attack):-

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db ("new");
$newusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newusername']);
$newpassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newpassword']);
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
if($submit) 
{
    $newaccount = "INSERT INTO users (name, password) VALUES ('$newusername', '$newpassword')";
    $result = mysql_query($newaccount);
    if ($result) 
    {
        print "account has been created"."<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;login.php'>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo " The account is already exist";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Although this would work and fixes the problem(s), guess what; OP's site apparently got hacked http://stackoverflow.com/q/24966531/ - You'll be able to see it if the question gets deleted since you're a `10k+` member. OP should have been using prepared statements along with using proper password hashing algos.

Answer (score -1):

```
$newaccount= "INSERT INTO users (name,password) VALUES ("$newusername","$newpassword")";
```

**TO**

```
$newaccount= "INSERT INTO users (name,password) VALUES ('".$newusername."','".$newpassword."')";
```

**OR TO**

```
$newaccount= "INSERT INTO users (name,password) VALUES ('$newusername','$newpassword')";
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    mysql_connect ("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db ("new");
    $newusername=$_POST ['newusername'];
    $newpassword=$_POST ['newpassword'];
    $submit=$_POST ['submit'];
    if($submit) {
    $newaccount= "INSERT INTO users (name,password) VALUES ('".$newusername."', '".$newpassword."')";
    $result=mysql_query($newaccount);
    if ($result) {
    print "account has been created"."<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;login.php">";
    }
    else {
    echo " The account is already exist";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1